# Facebook: post image and description to wall and in page album via php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I want users to post an image on a facebook page via a form on a website.
When they have logged in via facebook on this website, they can select an image from their computer.

Once they have selected the image, I want it to be posted to the users wall, and in an album of the page where I'm one of the administrators.

I have created an app for this, but we can't seem to find a way to get the app to post on this facebook-page.

Do we need to set any permissions on this page or app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To upload images to a facebook page of which you're an admin you need to do the following:

1.) Create a facebook application (the usual way), make sure you specify the Canvas URL

2.) Navigate to the url below logged in as the admin of the page, and give the permissions (user_photos,manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream)

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id=<application_id>
    &redirect_uri=<canvas_url>
    &response_type=token
    &scope=user_photos,manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream
```

3.) When you give the application the required permissions you'll be redirected to canvas_url#access_token=*access_token*, for example

```
http://example.com/#access_token=awe12
```

4.) Then navigate to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=<access_token>
```

(use the access token from #3). This will list the pages you administer; write down the access_token for the page(s) to which you want to upload the image

I'm not 100% sure but I believe that using graph api you can upload images only to albums created via graph api; i.e. you need to first create an album via graph api. Here's sample code using curl:

```
$uri = sprintf( 
    'https://graph.facebook.com/%1$s/albums?access_token=%2$s',
    $page_id, 
    $access_token
);

$post_fields = array(
    'name' => trim( $album_name )
);

$curl = curl_init( $uri );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );  
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields );  

$raw_data = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );

$data = json_decode( $raw_data, $assoc = TRUE );
```

The `$data` above will contain the album id, which you'll need to upload a photo:

```
// prepare the curl post fields
$batch = sprintf(
    '[{"method":"POST", "relative_url":"%1$s/photos", "attached_files":"file1"}]',
    $album_id
);  

$post_fields = array(
    'batch' => $batch,
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'file1' => '@' . $image_abs_path
);
$uri = 'https://graph.facebook.com';

$curl = curl_init( $uri );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );  
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields );  

$raw_data = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );

$data = json_decode( $raw_data, $assoc = TRUE );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply yesterday. But I still have a problem. I always need to generate the access-token of the page by hand. Is there a way to get a acces-token of this page that doesn't expire?

Comment: if you added the `offline_access` in step 2.) the access token should not expire

Comment: I did this, but in the response there is still a expiring time. It's about 7000 seconds long.

Comment: I found that the token retrieved did in fact expire. HOWEVER, from reading https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ it seems like I found out you can hit https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN and this will return an access_token valid for 60 days

Comment: sorry but it's been a while since I tried ... it was posted over 3 years ago and I'd be very surprised if image upload via API was still this complicated , i.e it either works better or not at all. I'm pretty sure non-expiring tokens were disabled a long ago.