# Facebook Graph API - Using, 'app access token' to fetch facebook page feeds (Solution)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Well, this may sound strange. When a facebook application is configured to be a Native/Desktop app (Apps->Your APP->Advanced->App type), the 'app access token' obtain from this procedure

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" + "client_id=" +
>   APP_ID + "&client_secret=" + APP_SEC +
>   "&grant_type=client_credentials"

Will not work, to fetch feeds or post from a Facebook page. As per facebook documentation 
fetching  feeds only requires **any valid access_token or user access_token**, strange enough it doesn't work this way, if the app is configured to be Native/Desktop.

[1](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=349550) Solution, found after a days research, came to frustrating conclusion that it has to be configured as 'web' based application in (Apps->Your APP->Advanced->App type).

Once set up, the above procedure to fetch feeds works.This gives raise to a question, is this a bug ? or have i misunderstood the documentation.

I hope i have saved a day for you, if you have been working on facebook page feeds these days and pulling your hair off, out of frustration for obvious reasons.

[[1] Facebook forum post](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=349550)

Comment: What you need is the access_token for the facebook page - read this on how to get that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395356/facebook-post-image-and-description-to-wall-and-in-page-album-via-php/9395916#9395916 - then just use the graph api as if you were getting feeds for a normal user (using the facebook page id and the given access token)

Comment: praise you, appType does matter. I was trying to get raw JSON data of various public feeds but since 2012 it required user token which expired after 60 days, this way just using appID+appSecret->appToken I can have simple access to public facebook data again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the relevant documentation about *Use an App Access Token*

> App Access Tokens should only be used when the posting functions are originated directly from your servers in order to keep them private to the app. For example, you should not publish using an App Access Token from within a client such as a native mobile app. Doing that could allow individuals to obtain the App Access Token, which could then allow them to take actions on behalf of your app. Instead, you should have your native mobile app queue actions up with your server and then have your server publish the stories to Facebook using the App Access Token. For this reason, if your 'App Type' in Settings > Advanced is set to 'Native/Desktop', we assume that your client app contains the App Secret or an App Access Token in its binary, and do not allow calls signed with an App Access Token to proceed. The API will behave as though no access token was provided.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/)

**Also about *Obtaining an App Access Token*:**

> Because it requires you to include your App Secret you should not attempt to make this call client-side as that would expose this secret to all your app users. It is important that your App Secret is never shared with anyone. For this reason, this call should be performed server-side [...]

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/)