# How to get facebook page rss feed (everyone)

Tags: facebook, rss

If you view facebook page, they are link left-bottom shows rss feed for facebook page, but unfortunately, the feed only shows status update by page owner, is there anyway to get feed from everyone who post the new status in the page....

Answer (score 21):

There's another way to get the feed from a public Facebook page as RSS, which is entirely public and can be retrieved anonymously; i.e. requires no Facebook connect or other stuff. The format for the URL of the RSS feed is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID&format=rss20
```

Where `PAGE_ID` is the Facebook ID of the page. Or even better, as JSON:

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID&format=json
```

Comment: do you have a working example of this? I don't think rss is supported anymore.

Comment: Sure @MotoTribe, here's the feed from a popular fan page for Gil Scott Heron, `https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=11510137267&format=json`

Comment: To add something: in case you do not know your numeric ID, check [this page](http://findmyfacebookid.com/) out.

Comment: I get data with a summary that contains: "This feed URL is no longer valid".

Comment: Verified this does indeed work for RSS 2.0 format, provided you use the *numeric ID* for the page.

Besides the link provided by JNat, you can get your numeric ID by substituting 'www' for 'graph' in your URL.  For example:

    http://www.facebook.com/myProfile

becomes

    http://graph.facebook.com/myProfile

Refer to the "id" parameter.  It's also useful for seeing just how much data you're making public.

Comment: @MickByrne There is a limitation in this output for non Latin languages such as Arabic. The title text is encoded incorrectly for those languages. For example:
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=298887790292424

Comment: Seems broken now? 
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=3004989

Comment: Facebook changed its policies, and at the moment this method doesn't  work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/, get the access_token like this: [Facebook: post image and description to wall and in page album via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395356/facebook-post-image-and-description-to-wall-and-in-page-album-via-php/9395916#9395916)

Comment: oh sound difficult, im not coder, just think its easy like this only  https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=[page-id]&format=rss20  and then for everyone just be like this https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=[page-id]&format=rss20&everyone

Answer (score 0):

These guys seems to be providing an API as well here - https://randomtools.io/developer-api/