# post content to facebook (product, brand) page from desktop app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am going trough Facebook developer pages looking for right answer but all seems so confusing there and I just can't figure out the right (and easiest) thing I need. So if anyone can provide a simple answer or www link on what I need to know here is my question: I need to post things (photos and/or text) to our Facebook brand page wall from a Desktop application.

I know I can send an email to email address assigned to our brand page, but I don't want to go this way. Is there another way of posting photos to Facebook brand pages? If yes how and what are the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get access_token for the page; then use the token to post as if you were posting to a regular facebook user's feed - here's info on how to get page access_token [Facebook: post image and description to wall and in page album via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395356/facebook-post-image-and-description-to-wall-and-in-page-album-via-php/9395916#9395916)

Comment: So to do this I will need to create a Facebook canvas app? Is this truly necessary? I don't want to have Canvas application ...

Comment: well that's just one way to do it; you won't need to keep the canvas app, its purpose is only to give you an `access_token` with `manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream` permissions which you'll need in step #4. If you can get this token for the page's admin user you can go directly to step #4. Once you get to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=<access_token>`  the access_token values you get for the pages you administer are in no way connected to the canvas app you created in #1