# Post on a page on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

How can I (programatically, duh!) post on my page on facebook? I'm talking about an actual `Page` in the sense of the Facebook API, e.g. like [this](https://www.facebook.com/platform).

I read my way through most of the Graph API, but I can't really come to grips of which endpoint to use in order to post something.

I already roughly know how to get my authentication, but when I want to access my page through the graph API, it just returns `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get access_token for the page - read this on how to get the right access_token (just change the permissions to what you need) - [Facebook: post image and description to wall and in page album via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395356/facebook-post-image-and-description-to-wall-and-in-page-album-via-php/9395916#9395916)

once you have the right token you post the same way as to any user's feed, e.g. `https://graph.facebook.com/<page_id>/feed`